# Can we place multiple search conditions on the same for loop in python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Beginner to python, Can someone please explain me the meaning of the below for statement I have found in a code I have to understand:-

```
for _,s in self.current_links:
```

then some action, Lets say.

"current_links" is a list here. I am not able to figure out the significance of "_" after for. Can we place multiple conditions for the same for loop? Does the statement mean to search for _ & s both in the list and then proceed further?

Comment: _ here is just another variable.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it looks more like the `self.current_lines` is a 2-item that's being unpacked, and that the first item is using the `_` naming convention to indicate it's not really required, eg:

```
items = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
for _, item in items:
    print item # Gives 2 4 6
```

So the above works by taking each item in the list, eg `[1,2]` then *unpacking* to the variables on the left of the assignment - `_` and `item`: `_` gets the value `1` and `item` gets the value `2`... The `_` is indicating it's not really required.

However, sometimes `_` is used for `gettext` and similar so to avoid cluttering the namespace and potentially mucking that up, it could also be written as:

```
for item in (item[1] for item in items):
    print item
```

Comment: unpacking into a placeholder variable is often much more readable, but because `_` is used for so many things, I tend to do something like `for _dontcare, item in ...`.  alternatively, a more streamlined version of your second example is `for item in map(operator.itemgetter(1), items)`

Answer (score 0):

`_` here is just another variable here.

`_` will hold the index of the list and `s` will hold the value of the list.

Comment: If the OP's code was using `enumerate` this would make sense - however, it's not, and even if it were - there's little point in discarding the index - you just wouldn't use `enumerate` to start with.